# Plugin to handle shipping costs based on order value and location in Shopify

Tags: ecommerce, plug-in, shopping-cart

I would like to know what would be the most sensible way to achieve the following on our Shopify site:

1. Delivery Charge Per State
2. Free shipping for orders > minimum order value

The only snag is we need to define point 2 per state. For Example...

(We are based in Australia)

- New South Wales -> Minimum order value = $100, therefore all orders less than $100 will get the delivery charge for NSW
- Victoria -> Minimum order value = $150, therefore all orders less than $150 will get the delivery charge for VIC
- etc...

I am suspecting there may be a plugin that could accommodate this type of scenario, or even better if there is a native way to deal with this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Wouldn’t delivery cost also be influenced by the (size of the) items being shipped? And doesn’t your shipper have an API to provide cost?

Comment: @mawg - no, weight and size not a factor, just minimum order value. Basically if order value is less than a threshold per state, we charge a delivery surcharge per state